# Matrix over GF(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coding-theory

Let B be a square matrix, let I be identity matrix of the same size, and let G be the generator matrix in standard form created by appending B to I. Prove that the code over GF(2) generated by G is self-dual.  I'm stuck on how to get the relationship that B*B^T=I. B^T means the transpose of B.

Comment: check if the parity check matrix of the code is also a generator matrix of the code.

Comment: I tried it, but it turned out that I need to prove the equation I posted on the question.

Comment: I am fairly sure that the exercise is to prove the code is self-dual if and only if $BB^T=I$. Such a code is definitely not always self-dual as you seem to claim.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No, that's the question. I also hope the question is in that way.

Comment: Then your teacher (or the author of the book/lecture notes) made a mistake. Or it is mistranslated. The code is not self-dual for all choices of $B$. Only for those satisfying the matrix equation $BB^T$. As an example of what will go wrong I mention that for some choices of $B$ the resulting code will have words of an odd weight. Immediately violating self-duality.

Answer (score 1):

As posed, the statement is not always true. Consider for example the following generator matrix G:

$$G=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1&1\\0&1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

It answers all the requirements, yet $BB^t\neq I$ and the code generated by this matrix obviously isn't self-dual (easy to check - the first codeword in $G$ times itself isn't $0$).

Perhaps there are further details regarding $B$ or the code? Perhaps $B$ is given?